# Loop Foreach only repeat offline computers

Tags: powershell

Not sure where I am going wrong I want to skip the computers which are coming back online but it keeps checking both online and online computers.

1st update is fine that its coming online and it should skip and only ping the offline one's a screenhot of output

```
g-10 Is coming online...Skipping to offline one's
192.168.0.1 Is coming online...Skipping to offline one's
Testing to see if Hero is coming online...
Hero is Offline. Pausing for 2 seconds. Remaining attempts: 1
Testing to see if zero is coming online...
zero is Offline. Pausing for 2 seconds. Remaining attempts: 1
```

Its fine upto here but online computers again repeated...

```
 g-10 Is coming online...Skipping to offline one's
    192.168.0.1 Is coming online...Skipping to offline one's
    Testing to see if Hero is coming online...
    Hero is Offline.
```

here is my code

```
$Comps = GC c:\restarted.txt
[int]$SleepTimer = "1" #minutes to attempt after
[int]$SleepSeconds = $SleepTimer * 2
[int]$Attempts = "2"
[int]$AttemptsCounter = 0

Do 
{
   $AttemptsCounter++
   $RemainingAttempts = ([int]$Attempts - [int]$AttemptsCounter)
   Foreach($comp in $comps){
   $Online = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Comp -Quiet
   IF($online -eq "True"){
  Write-Host "$comp" -BackgroundColor Green  -NoNewline
   Write-Host " Is coming online...Skipping to offline one's"
   }

   elseIf ($Online -NE "True") 
   {
      Write-Host "Testing to see if $Comp is coming online..."
      Write-Host "$comp" -BackgroundColor Red  -NoNewline
       Write-Host " is Offline" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Black -NoNewline
       If ($AttemptsCounter -eq $Attempts) {
          Write-Host "."
       }
       Else {
          Write-Host ". Pausing for $SleepSeconds seconds. Remaining attempts: $RemainingAttempts"
       }
   }
}
   #Check the number of attempts, break out if reached.
   If ($AttemptsCounter -eq $Attempts) {break}

   #Delay
   Start-Sleep -s ($SleepTimer * 60)
}
While ($Online -NE "True")

If ($Online -NE "True") {
   Write-Host "Maximum number of attempts reached"
   }
Else {
   Write-Host
   Write-Host "Computer $Comp is " -NoNewline
   Write-Host "ONLINE" -BackgroundColor Green
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code.

It basically does the following for each line in `c:\restarted.txt`:

1. tests if the computer is online (Note: I added `-Count 1`)
2. if it is `online`: prints some green text and `break`
3. if it is `offline`: print red text, wait and decrements the $RemainingAttempts variable and redo until `$RemainingAttempts` is `0` or the computer is `online`
4. it the `$RemainingAttempts` variable is `0` print out some more text

   ```
   $ComputerNameArray = Get-Content -Path c:\restarted.txt
   [int]$SleepTimer = "1" #minutes to attempt after
   [int]$Attempts = "2"
   $DefaultBackgroundColor = (Get-Host).ui.rawui.BackgroundColor

   foreach($ComputerName in $ComputerNameArray) {
       $AttemptsCounter = 0
       $RemainingAttempts = $Attempts - $AttemptsCounter

       Write-Host "Testing to see if ""$ComputerName"" is coming online..." -BackgroundColor $DefaultBackgroundColor

       while($RemainingAttempts -gt 0) {
           if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Quiet -Count 1) {
               Write-Host """$ComputerName""" -BackgroundColor Green  -NoNewline
               Write-Host " Is coming online...Skipping to offline one's"
               break
           } else {
               Write-Host """$ComputerName""" -BackgroundColor Red  -NoNewline
               Write-Host " is Offline" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Black -NoNewline
               Write-Host ". Pausing for $SleepTimer minutes. Remaining attempts: $($RemainingAttempts - 1)"
               Start-Sleep -Seconds ($SleepTimer * 60)
               $RemainingAttempts--
           }
       }

       if($RemainingAttempts -eq 0) {
           Write-Host "Maximum number of attempts reached" -BackgroundColor $DefaultBackgroundColor
       }
   }
   ```

hope this helps!

Let me know if you have any question concerning the code.

KR
Guenther

Answer (score 0):

`Test-Connection` returns an array of objects or a $null depending if the ip or hostname is live.

so its enough if you do this:

```
IF($online){
  // if its alive
}
else
{
  // if its not responding
}
```

another thing to point out is you dont have to

```
if(condition) {
}
elseif(condition) {
}
```

if you are testing "bool question-answer" you don't need the `elseif`. In your case, if you are checking the state of computer then you can't have more answers than 2 (yes/no). So the `elseif` is in this case redundant.

```
if(condition) {
  // if the condition is true
}
else {
  // if the condition is not true. you can't have the third option
}
```

Also your if condition `If ($Online -NE "True")` is checking if the variable `$Online` is not equal the exact string "true" or "True" since `-ne` is case insensitive condition operator.
You should check if the variable holds anything or holds `$Null`

Comment: `Test-Connection -Quiet` returns a `boolean`.  Without `-Quiet` you are correct, it returns an array or `$null` on failure.

Answer (score 0):

While I know Guenther Schmitz has already got the green check, I wanted to follow up with some additional details and pointers.

`Test-Connection` with the `-Quiet` switch returns a `[Boolean]` type.  This is a simple true/false.  I like to be extra careful with comparing string values to Boolean values because you can get some odd results depending on how you frame your tests.  For example:

```
'false' -eq $true
$true -eq 'false'
```

Top one equals false, bottom one equals true because PowerShell is converting the second object into the same type as the first, and a non-empty string is true. So my *strong* recommendation is to stick to typed comparisons.  So the first code change I'd start with is:

```
if ($Online -eq $true) {
```

As @pandemic already mentioned, you're doing a simple comparison, so no need for `elseif`, just `else`.

The second issue you have is that there is nothing removing computers from your testing list.  The way your code is written, if the last computer in your testing list is "down" then it'd go through all the computers again.  If the last computer in the list is "up" then it'd quit the `do|while` loop, irregardless of how many computers you are testing and how many are down.  You can verify this with a simple test of putting 1 known hosts, and 1 fake host in the test file. If the known good host is first, it'll keep looping until `$AttemptsCounter` reaches the maximum allowed. If you flip the list around, it'll bail out immediately after testing the known good host.

Your initial code looped through all the computers once then went back and started again. In Guenther's example, they loop one computer at a time, and check until it comes up, or bail out after exceeding the test count. I think Guenther's example was probably what you were after, but if you wanted to make it cycle through all the computers, and then test only those that had failed, I'd write something like this:

```
$comps = Get-Content -path 'c:\restarted.txt'
[int]$SleepTimer = 1
[int]$Attempts = 2
[int]$AttemptsCounter = 0

do {
    Write-Host "Testing Network, attempt $($AttemptsCount + 1)"
    $newComps = @()
    foreach($comp in $comps) {
        $online = Test-Connection -Quiet -Count 1 -ComputerName $comp
        if ($online) {
            Write-Host "$comp" -BackgroundColor Green  -NoNewline
            Write-Host " Is coming online...Skipping to offline one's"
        } else {
            $newComps += $comp
            Write-Host "$comp" -BackgroundColor Red  -NoNewline
            Write-Host " is Offline" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Black
        }
    }
    $comps = $newComps
    $AttemptsCounter++
    Start-Sleep -Seconds ($SleepTimer * 60)
}
while (($comps.count -gt 0) -and ($AttemptsCounter -lt $Attempts))

if ($comps.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Exceeded Attempts Counter" -BackgroundColor Red
}
```

In this code, it is taking the list of computers, and when it fails on a computer, it stuffs it into a temporary list for reuse.

Comment: wow your idea is also good im testing it, assume that 3 computers are offline and it says 3 are offline and in the mean while is it going to skip the one that is online? thats fun playing with this script